# How am I able to export all of my applications' names on my Mac into a CSV or TXT file?

Tags: macos, applications

How am I able to export all of my applications' names on my Mac into a CSV or TXT file? I am currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

Comment: When you say _"all of my applications"_, do you mean in the `/Applications` folder or all executables on the filesystem everywhere?

Comment: I mean the `/Applications` folder.

Comment: It is possible to select all of the applications, copy them, then paste into a text file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a Terminal:

```
mdfind kMDItemKind="Application" > ~/Desktop/apps.txt
```

This will create a file named `apps.txt` on your Desktop, containing the full paths for everything that OS X considers to be an "Application" on your system.

This is might be a lot more than you want. You can limit the search to a given folder by adding `-onlyin <dir>`, so:

```
mdfind -onlyin /Applications kMDItemKind="Application" > ~/Desktop/apps.txt
```

will limit the search to the `/Applications` folder (and its subfolders). Note that you might also have apps under `~/Applications`, i.e., inside your Home folder.

In which case, you would call `onlyin` again:

```
mdfind -onlyin /Applications -onlyin ~/Applications kMDItemKind="Application" > ~/Desktop/apps.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Within Finder, open the application folder
2. Select All (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then Copy (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Open a new document in TextEdit
4. Now go to Edit > Paste and Match Style (or use <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
5. Save the text file

Comment: simple & accurate answer.